# Error when combining three JOIN queries into one (UNION)

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I am trying to combine three queries into a UNION query, however I am receiving a UNION syntax error

```
SELECT distinct(db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID), LOC, 
USER_TYPE, db_tbl_customers_Record_Count, t_count_m1
FROM db_tbl_full 
LEFT JOIN qry_cs_t_count_m1 ON db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID=qry_cs_t_count_m1.db_tbl_customers_C_ID

UNION

SELECTdistinct(db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID, LOC, 
USER_TYPE, nm1.db_tbl_customers_Record_Count, t_count_m1, t_count_m2
FROM db_tbl_full 
LEFT JOIN qry_cs_t_count_m2 
ON nm1.db_tbl_customers_C_ID=qry_cs_t_count_m2.db_tbl_customers_C_ID

UNION

SELECT distinct(db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID), LOC, 
USER_TYPE, nm2.db_tbl_customers_Record_Count, t_count_m1, 
t_count_m2, t_count_m3
FROM db_tbl_full 
LEFT JOIN qry_cs_t_count_m3 
ON nm2.db_tbl_customers_C_ID=qry_cs_t_count_m3.db_tbl_customers_C_ID
ORDER BY nm2.db_tbl_customers_C_ID;
```

Any help with correcting the syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is `SELECT` and `distinct` stuck together in your code 2nd query, or is it just a typo here?

Answer (score 0):

You have different numbers of columns in the different subqueries.  Try this:

```
SELECT distinct db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID, LOC, 
       USER_TYPE, db_tbl_customers_Record_Count, t_count_m1,
       NULL as t_count_m2, NULL as t_count_m3
FROM db_tbl_full LEFT JOIN
     qry_cs_t_count_m1
     ON db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID = qry_cs_t_count_m1.db_tbl_customers_C_ID

UNION

SELECT distinct db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID, LOC, 
       USER_TYPE, nm1.db_tbl_customers_Record_Count, t_count_m1, t_count_m2, NULL as t_count_m3
FROM db_tbl_full LEFT JOIN
     qry_cs_t_count_m2 
     ON nm1.db_tbl_customers_C_ID = qry_cs_t_count_m2.db_tbl_customers_C_ID

UNION

SELECT distinct db_tbl_full.db_tbl_customers_C_ID, LOC, 
       USER_TYPE, nm2.db_tbl_customers_Record_Count, t_count_m1, 
       t_count_m2, t_count_m3
FROM db_tbl_full LEFT JOIN
     qry_cs_t_count_m3 
     ON nm2.db_tbl_customers_C_ID = qry_cs_t_count_m3.db_tbl_customers_C_ID
ORDER BY nm2.db_tbl_customers_C_ID;
```

You also understand that the parentheses around the `distinct` have no effect.  The `distinct` applies to the entire row.